# Augmented Dickey Fuller Test: Always lag=1?

Tags: r, time-series, unit-root, lags, augmented-dickey-fuller

I do have a question related to the ur.df test in R with the (urca package). The data comprises a monthly time series over a span of 48 months.

When testing my variables for a unit root, my results look like this:

```
summary(ur.df(as.matrix(data[1]), type ="trend", lags=12, selectlags="BIC"))
```

A

```
############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 

Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-19649529  -5517521  -1103167   3946889  22894535 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.598e+07  5.484e+06   2.914 0.006575 ** 
z.lag.1     -9.573e-01  2.621e-01  -3.652 0.000951 ***
tt           3.259e+05  1.964e+05   1.659 0.107105    
z.diff.lag   1.111e-01  2.015e-01   0.551 0.585533    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 8601000 on 31 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4302,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.375 
F-statistic: 7.801 on 3 and 31 DF,  p-value: 0.0005072


Value of test-statistic is: -3.7521 4.5517 7.1516 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -4.15 -3.50 -3.28
phi2  7.01  5.12  4.31
phi3  9.30  6.72  5.11
```

Only one of the variables shows more than 1 lag in the output:

```
summary(ur.df(as.matrix(data[14]), type ="trend", lags=12, selectlags="BIC"))
```

B

```
############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.65651 -0.23142  0.07356  0.23250  0.46200 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) 26.08643   10.42330   2.503   0.0187 *
z.lag.1     -1.44007    0.58065  -2.480   0.0197 *
tt           0.03693    0.01838   2.010   0.0545 .
z.diff.lag1  0.53866    0.54632   0.986   0.3329  
z.diff.lag2  0.35904    0.45038   0.797   0.4323  
z.diff.lag3  0.19584    0.35081   0.558   0.5813  
z.diff.lag4  0.01899    0.26065   0.073   0.9425  
z.diff.lag5  0.43722    0.17187   2.544   0.0170 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 0.371 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7863,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7309 
F-statistic: 14.19 on 7 and 27 DF,  p-value: 1.404e-07

Value of test-statistic is: -2.3801 2.6439 3.5234 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -4.15 -3.50 -3.18
phi2  7.02  5.13  4.31
phi3  9.31  6.73  5.61
```

After reading a few related posts here, I conclude:

A: There is a unit root in the time series for lag 1 that is significant at 1% level.

B:  No unit root, though I am unsure whether the tested statistics -2.3801 belongs to lag 1 or 5, which seem both significant at 5% level?

**Questions**:

1. Are the conclusions correct?
2. Does it seem odd that most of my variables do have a unit root at lag=1 or is that okay?